# Let $p_n = n$th odd prime. When is $p_n$ a continuous function of $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, continuity, prime-numbers

Under what topologies is the function $p(n) = n$th odd prime continuous?  If we take the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{R}$ and induced it onto the subspace $\Bbb{N}$ and called it $\tau$.  Then isn't $p(n)$ continuous from $(\Bbb{N}, \tau)$ to itself?

Comment: primes in the sense of rings ? or in the sense of generators of a multiplicative group (or monoid) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induced topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is simply the discrete
topology (all subsets are open), so any function $f\colon(\mathbb{N},\tau)\rightarrow(\mathbb{N},\tau)$ is trivially continuous (but, this isn't particularly interesting).